# How do I prevent illegal state in renders when useEffect only fires after render?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a React component that takes a prop and holds state via `useState`. When that prop changes, I sometimes need to update the state in response, so I added a `useEffect`. But props changes cause a render, `useEffect` fires after that render, and setting state causes another `render`, and between those two renders, my component is in an illegal state, and I don't know how to prevent it.

---

Here's a trivial example. This component displays a list of radio buttons each representing a city. Only the radio buttons for the cities within a specific country are enabled at one time. When the country changes, it updates which radio buttons are enabled and it also changes the user's selection to be a valid city.

```
import { useEffect, useState } from 'react';

const CITIES_BY_COUNTRY = {
  Spain: ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia'],
  France: ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille'],
};

export function CityPicker({ currentCountry }) {
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('');

  // When the country changes, make sure the selected city is valid.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (!CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry].includes(selectedCity)) {
      setSelectedCity(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry][0]);
    }
  }, [currentCountry, selectedCity]);

  // Log the country/city pair.
  console.log({ currentCountry, selectedCity });

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY).map(country => (
        <div key={`country-${country}`}>
          {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[country]).map(city => (
            <label key={`city-${city}`}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="city"
                value={city}
                disabled={country !== currentCountry}
                checked={city === selectedCity}
                onChange={() => setSelectedCity(city)}
              />
              {city}
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

1. User arrives with currentCountry === "Spain". Only Spanish cities are enabled. Log says `{ currentCountry: "Spain", selectedCity: "Madrid" }`
2. User clicks “Barcelona”. Log says `{ currentCountry: "Spain", selectedCity: "Barcelona" }`. All good up to this point.
3. Something in the parent component changes and the `currentCountry` changes to France. This component gets passed the new prop and re-renders. Log says `{ currentCountry: "France", selectedCity: "Barcelona" }`. THEN, the `useEffect` fires and we get another render. Log says `{ currentCountry: "France", selectedCity: "Paris" }`.

As you can see, we got two renders in step 3, and one of them had an illegal pair (France+Barcelona).

This is a trivial example, and my app is much more complicated. There's many ways that both the country and city can change and I need to perform validation on the pair each time and sometimes prompt the user or otherwise react in certain circumstances. Given that, it's really important to prevent illegal pairs.

---

Given that `useEffect` only ever fires after a render, it seems like it will always be too late to make the change I need. Is there an elegant way to solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

June 2022 Update: I've discovered a new solution using a relatively hidden React feature.

To sync props, you can set state directly inside the render, and as soon as your render returns, React will update state and re-render! This is not only encouraged in [the official React docs](https://beta.reactjs.org/learn/you-might-not-need-an-effect#adjusting-some-state-when-a-prop-changes), but a similar example to my original is presented as "what not to do".

Factoring this in, here's my new solution:

```
import { useState } from 'react';

const CITIES_BY_COUNTRY = {
  Spain: ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia'],
  France: ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille'],
};

export function CityPicker({ currentCountry }) {
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('');

  // When the country changes, make sure the selected city is valid.
  // NOTE: No useEffect here. React will re-render immediately after
  // first render.
  if (!CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry].includes(selectedCity)) {
    setSelectedCity(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry][0]);
  }

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY).map(country => (
        <div key={`country-${country}`}>
          {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[country]).map(city => (
            <label key={`city-${city}`}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="city"
                value={city}
                disabled={country !== currentCountry}
                checked={city === selectedCity}
                onChange={() => setSelectedCity(city)}
              />
              {city}
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's my best attempt at a solution, although I don't find it elegant. I wonder if some of this can be abstracted into a custom hook somehow.

```
export function EffectiveCityPicker({ currentCountry }) {
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry][0]);

  // Based on the country, make sure we have a valid city.
  let effectiveSelectedCity = selectedCity;
  if (!CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry].includes(selectedCity)) {
    effectiveSelectedCity = CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry][0];
  }

  // If the effectiveSelectedCity changes, save it back to state.
  useEffect(() => {
    if (selectedCity !== effectiveSelectedCity) {
      setSelectedCity(effectiveSelectedCity);
    }
  }, [selectedCity, effectiveSelectedCity]);

  // Log the country/city pair.
  console.log({ currentCountry, effectiveSelectedCity });

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY).map(country => (
        <div key={`country-${country}`}>
          {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[country]).map(city => (
            <label key={`city-${city}`}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="city"
                value={city}
                disabled={country !== currentCountry}
                checked={city === effectiveSelectedCity}
                onChange={() => setSelectedCity(city)}
              />
              {city}
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

In this version, we always combine the current props and state to form a valid `effectiveSelectedCity`, and then save it back to state afterwards if needed. It prevents the illegal pair, but it results in an extra render that produces the same markup. It also gets way more complicated if there's more state and props -- perhaps there's a similar solution that uses a reducer.

Answer (score 0):

`useMemo` works in this case while preventing extra render.
To prevent such problems as you described, you can make both - country and city selection a controlled components and manage their state from parent (pass value and handler as props).

```
import { useMemo, useState } from 'react';

const CITIES_BY_COUNTRY = {
  Spain: ['Madrid', 'Barcelona', 'Valencia'],
  France: ['Paris', 'Lyon', 'Marseille'],
};

export function CityPicker({ currentCountry }) {
  const [selectedCity, setSelectedCity] = useState('');

  const currentCity = useMemo(() => {
     const defaultCity = CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry][0];
     const isCityValid = CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[currentCountry].includes(selectedCity);
     return isCityValid ? selectedCity : defaultCity;
  }, [selectedCity, currentCountry]);

  return (
    <div>
      {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY).map(country => (
        <div key={`country-${country}`}>
          {Object.keys(CITIES_BY_COUNTRY[country]).map(city => (
            <label key={`city-${city}`}>
              <input
                type="radio"
                name="city"
                value={city}
                disabled={country !== currentCountry}
                checked={city === currentCity}
                onChange={() => setSelectedCity(city)}
              />
              {city}
            </label>
          ))}
        </div>
      ))}
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Your suggestion works for validating the user's actions on selection, but it doesn't address the larger issue: If `currentCountry` (the prop) changes, your code doesn't change the city at all, and you'd be left with an illegal pair.

Comment: @BrentTraut edited example to meet your requirements.
Now the city is memoized and if country will change, you will still have a valid city. But if country will be changed back without changing city, previously selected city will be restored.
If such behavior is not what you want, simplest way would be to move the state up, where you could reset cities state in countries change handler while preventing extra render.

Comment: This seems reasonable enough. As it stands, my example is an extremely simplified version of what I'm trying to accomplish and I'm not sure the example extrapolates well to the full requirements, but I'm also not sure how to boil my needs down to a StackOverflow-friendly question. Given that, I'm accepting this answer and I'll try to build on it for my own purposes.

Comment: One last insight here: this `useMemo` approach as well as the potential solution I added -- both seem like an approximation of `getDerivedStateFromProps` from the old class components. Seeing this parallel makes me more comfortable with the solution.